# Cisco AnyConnect on Raspbian

Tags: networking, raspbian, vpn, cisco

How can I use Cisco AnyConnect on Rasbian OS?
`apt-get install anyconnect` is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use [OpenConnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/) which was originally developed to access AnyConnect VPNs. You'll need to know the address of your VPN (if you have a computer already set up with AnyConnect you can use that to find the address). It [should work on Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=83844), too.

Comment: Thanks drewbenn.  
I have done following steps as root:  
apt-get install openconnect  
openconnect -u username -b gate.mydomain.com  
Password:  
....  
It is working well!